# Camera positional tracking using python

Tags: python, position, tracking, indoor-positioning-system

I am working on a project and I need to track the movement of a camera position.
I found out that it can be done if I am using ZED camera
like shown on this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MTFU2OgtCNU).

But I was wondering if it is possible to do so using a notebook webcam or a phone camera.
Is there any python libraries that support that already?